# Problem with git push and entering password

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've just setup an account on bitbucket and trying to import my repository for the first time.

I type this command:

git push -u origin --all

Then I am prompted for my password. When I hit enter a new line is inserted and nothing happens. I can also see my password on the screen. For example if my password was "mypassword" this is what it would look like after I run the command, hit enter, enter password and hit enter:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you pressing enter right after the `Password:` prompt shows up?

Comment: Nope. I hit enter after the "git push -u origin --all" and then start typing.

Answer (score 3):

ooh, this post is pretty old but,

when setting the remote repository try to use:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
```

instead of:

```
git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get code from an existing bitbucket repo then you need to run this command:

`git clone https://<your-user-name>@bitbucket.org/<your-user-name>/<project-name>.git`

But if you are trying to push code to your bitbucket a/c from your local git repo, then see here for further help: [Importing code from an existing project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project)

Look to the section that says "**Import an existing, unversioned code project to an empty repository**".

Comment: Thanks, I've done the steps in the "Importing code from an existing project" but when I get to step 9 "Follow the directions in the pane for your repository" is where I run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, have problems using ssh authentication on bitbucket; this is how I fixed it. Bitbucket desires it's own separate ssh key for each individual user from what I can gather from the documentation.

Use your default method to make a new ssh key specifically for bitbucket (we'll call the ssh key 'id_pub_my_user_name.pub') and place something similar the following in ~/.ssh/config:

```
# bitbucket user - my_user_name
Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User my_user_name
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my_user_name
```

If you now type in a terminal:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

It will now show you as authenticated, and you can happily go on from there.